# Depth first search has wrong output when cycle is encountered

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search

I am trying to implement a depth first search but I am having trouble when it comes to cycles within the directed graph.

```
directed_graph = {
    'a': ['b'],
    'b': ['c', 'd', 'e'],
    'c': ['d', 'e'],
    'd': ['a', 'e'],
    'e': ['f'],
    'f': [],
    'g': ['d']
}
```

Ignore the weights of each edge:

[image]

There is a cycle from `B -> C -> D -> A -> B`

```
def dfs(graph, start, end, visited=[]):
    if start == end:
        return True
    if start is None or end is None:
        return False
    queue = [start]
    if start not in visited:
        visited = visited + [start]

    node = queue.pop(0)

    for i in graph[node]:
        if i == end:
            return True
        if i not in visited:
            visited.append(i)
            return dfs(graph, i, end, visited)
    return False
```

When I run the function with `start = 'b'` and `end = 'f'` I get an output of `False` when if should be `True`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your program is that it only considers the first non-visited neighbor of each vertex. In the `for` loop, for each non-visited neighbor, `dfs` is called recursively. However, the result of this call will then be returned (meaning the `for` loop is aborted).  Therefore, other non-visited neighbors will not be considered.

In your example graph, the program visits the starting vertex `a` first. It then considers the first non-visited neighbor, which is `b`. At `b` it goes to the first non-visited neighbor, which is `d`. At `d`, the first non-visited neighbor is `a`. Since `a` has no non-visited neighbors (the only neighbor is `b`, which has already been visited), the `for` loop completes for `a` and the `return False` is reached for the `dfs` call for `a`. Back in the `dfs` call for `d`, the `for` loop will then be aborted to return the `False` given by the `dfs` call for `a`. This way, the `False` will be propagated up the call chain, resulting in the final `False` returned by your initial query.

To fix this, change the recursive call to `dfs`, such that the `for` loop is only aborted when the call returned `True`:

```
            if dfs(graph, i, end, visited):
              return True
```

With this fix, your program will give `True` for `start = 'b'` and `end = 'f'`.